# Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file

Tags: sql, insert

Нужно из файла с расширением csv добавить в таблицу данные.

Формат файла данных:
`Название;Номер1;Номер2;houseId;html_ссылка`
Формат таблицы: `houseid | html-ссылка |`
`houseid` в таблице является первичным и внешним ключом.
В запросе нужно пропустить из файла данных три столбика и добавить в таблицу два последних.

С помощью bcp я попытался сделать файл форматирования:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="200" 
COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="200" 
COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="200" 
COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="21"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="200" 
COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="HouseId" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Link" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Написал запрос:

```
    BULK INSERT dbo.Aeropanoramas
FROM 'c:\1\nmarket_aero.csv'
WITH
    ( ERRORFILE = 'c:\1\error_file.xml',
    FORMATFILE = 'c:\1\sql_format_file',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    TABLOCK )
```

Когда выполняю запрос, то получаю ошибку:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#OmitField), файл формата должен быть

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="200" COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="200" COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="200" COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="21"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="200"  COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="HouseId" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Link" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

А терминаторы в запросе - не нужны:

> Сведения в элементе `<ROW>` позволяют построить строку без
>   дополнительных сведений. По этой причине набор строк можно
>   сформировать при помощи инструкции
>
> `SELECT (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK datafile FORMATFILE=xmlformatfile)`